# double hover event using superfish menu

Tags: jquery, superfish

Here's the problem. I've created a menu with a dropdown menu using the superfish CSS approach. The main menu is an unordered list with each `<li>` containing a child `<a>` and a `<ul>`, e.g.

```
<ul class="sfmenu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">MENU 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><div>Stuff here</div></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><div>Stuff here</div></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><div>Stuff here</div></a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">MENU 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><div>Stuff here</div></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><div>Stuff here</div></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS for the top level `<li>` and `<a>` is:

```
.sf-menu li {
  color: #f9dfa0; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left; 
  height: 45px; 
  margin: 0
  padding: 0;
  padding: 20px 10px 0 10px;
}

.sf-menu a 
{
  font-weight: normal; 
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This positioning (padding) of the `<li>` results in a double hover effect when hovering over the `<li>` the dropdown appears and then when hovering over the `<a>` it drops down again. I have some jquery code to slidedown the submenu that works but I still get the double dropdown on hover. My jquery code is:

```
$(function() {
  $('.sf-menu li').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').hide().slideDown('normal');
  });
});
```

Is there anyway to remove the hover event from the `<a>` tag?

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test case:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
<li><span>unmatched</span></li>
<li><span>unmatched</span>
            <ul>
    <li><span>unmatched</span></li>
    <li><span>unmatched</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span>unmatched</span></li>
</ul>

<button onclick=' $(".sf-menu>li:not(li ul li)>span").text("matched");'></button>
```

click the button:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
<li><span>matched</span></li>
<li><span>matched</span>
            <ul>
    <li><span>unmatched</span></li>
    <li><span>unmatched</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span>matched</span></li>
</ul>
```

it was tricky to figure out, your code should be:

```
$(function() {
  $('.sf-menu>li:not(li ul li)').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').hide().slideDown('normal');
  });
});
```

UPDATED: This will cancel event bubbling when you mouseover the child elements:

```
$('.sf-menu>li>ul>li>a').mouseover(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: That definitely solves the double hover effect but the slideDown effect is gone as well.

Comment: have you got a link to the actual page?

Comment: What is missing from the test case is the `<a>` link in the `<li>` item. The test case does remove the double hover but something isn't quite correct because the slideDown effect does not work.